# flutter back button to Column visibility

Tags: android, flutter, dart

pressing back button to change any column's visibilty

for example:

```
Column1
Column2

Column1 Visible=true;
Column2 Visible=false;

***pressing back button***

Column1 Visible=false;
Column2 Visible=true;
```

Comment: device physical back button or the back button in appbar?

Comment: I am asking for "android physical back button"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are required to toggle the container visibility when the user presses the back button, you could handle the back button press by wrapping the body or scaffold widget with `WillPopScope` and handle the event

```
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Demo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Demo> createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  bool isVisible = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            setState(() {
              isVisible = !isVisible;
            });
            return Future.value(false);
          },
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Visibility(
                visible: isVisible,
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: !isVisible,
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```